# Multiple authorizer types for one endpoint in serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I’m doing some experimenting with serverless and authorizers for my API. I have a usecase where I have two different apps, one iOS and one Angular. The iOS app uses developer authentication with federated identities since it authenticates with a third party api, and the Angular app uses Cognito Userpools for authentication.

So i can specify a function with a User Pool authorizer and that works fine, and for my developer authentication users i’m using AWS_IAM authorizer and that works fine too.

But now i want my developer authenticated identities and my user pool users to be able to access the same api gateway endpoint. So how can I use two different types of authorizers for one endpoint?

Anyone with some experience in this that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually had the same problem. 
I ended up building a [custom authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) for this.

On the authorizer you can always do both validations.

Comment: You built AWS_IAM into your custom authorizer?  Can you share that implementation?

Comment: no, what i did was use the custom authorizer to verify cognito federated identities and other custom authentication i was using. AWS_IAM i assume you are refering to the aws sigv4 of the request that should be used with the AWS_IAM authorizer

Comment: Correct.  I'm looking to do what OP asked about but with sigv4 and jwt.